# Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection is not open

Tags: java, http, soap, connection, apache-axis

I am getting the below error while my code is trying to access a 3rd party endpoint
This request is sent via Service Stub generated code
We are using Axis2  version 1.7.7

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection is not open
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.assertOpen(HttpConnection.java:1277)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.getResponseInputStream(HttpConnection.java:858)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.getResponseInputStream(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1297)

What could be the reason for this and how can we solve this.

Below is the code for reference

```
public  com.test.Token validateToken(com.test.Token actionToken)throws java.rmi.RemoteException
{
org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext _messageContext = new org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext();
try{
org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient _operationClient = _serviceClient.createClient(_operations[0].getName());
_operationClient.getOptions().setAction("http://serviceURL/action");
_operationClient.getOptions().setExceptionToBeThrownOnSOAPFault(true);
addPropertyToOperationClient(_operationClient,org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL2Constants.ATTR_WHTTP_QUERY_PARAMETER_SEPARATOR,"&");
org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPEnvelope env = null;

env = toEnvelope(getFactory(_operationClient.getOptions().getSoapVersionURI()),
actionToken,
optimizeContent(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://serviceURL", "action")),
new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://serviceURL", "action"));

_serviceClient.addHeadersToEnvelope(env);
_messageContext.setEnvelope(env);

_operationClient.addMessageContext(_messageContext);

_operationClient.execute(true);
org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext _returnMessageContext = _operationClient.getMessageContext(
org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDLConstants.MESSAGE_LABEL_IN_VALUE);
org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPEnvelope _returnEnv = _returnMessageContext.getEnvelope();

java.lang.Object object = fromOM(
_returnEnv.getBody().getFirstElement() ,
com.test.Token.class);

return (com.test.Token)object;
}
```

Comment: it is going to be much harder trying to help you if you don't show us your code and don't summarize what you have tried. Please review [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Sergio I have added code for your reference